# if statement not resolving despite condition being met C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm working on a university assignment wherein I have to re-create the classic Frogger game. Having trouble with tyre movement.

```
for (int tZ = 0; tZ < kTyreColumnLength; tZ++)
{
    for (int tX = 0; tX < kTyreRowLength; tX++)
    {
        eachTyre = tX + tZ;
        tyre[eachTyre] = tyreMesh->CreateModel(0, -2.50, 0);
        tyre[eachTyre]->Scale(10);
        tyre[eachTyre]->SetX(tyreXs[tX]);
        tyre[eachTyre]->SetZ(tyreZs[tZ]);

        if (tZ % 2 == 0)
        {
            tyreMovingLeft[eachTyre];
        }
    }

}
```

Basically, the way I'm drawing my tyres is through nested for loops. The inner loop draws3 tyres, and is repeated for each row (outer loop)

I'm then trying to assign each "even" row tyre, a Boolean to track its direction.

**tZ % 2 ==0** IS correctly resolving to true/false each time the outer loop iterates, the debugger says the condition IS being met, but it's just never executing.

Comment: You are not doing anything with tyreMovingLeft

Comment: I am, just further down in my code. The issue according to debugger

Comment: How do you know "it's never executing"? There's nothing for it to execute...

Answer (score 1):

You never actually performed an assignment, you just indexed your array.

```
tyreMovingLeft[eachTyre];
```

You probably meant

```
tyreMovingLeft[eachTyre] = true;
```

Comment: Although if `tyreMovingLeft` is a map of, say, `bool`, then the result is already `tyreMovingLeft[eachType] = false;`. As usual, the question does not contain an MCVE so we cannot reliably answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Thr issue is that the inner block doesn’t have any effect:

```
 tyreMovingLeft[eachTyre];
```

So it's optimized out by compiler. Didn't yoy mean some assignment or passing the result to some function?

Comment: Although if `tyreMovingLeft` is a map of, say, `bool`, then the result is `tyreMovingLeft[eachType] = false;`. As usual, the question does not contain an MCVE so we cannot reliably answer it.